# How do I group switch buttons to control selection?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I have three `SwitchMaterial` switches inside my app that need to communicate with each other. I would like to control the selections based on current selections. For example if the first switch is set to true, then the next two should be true as well. If second and third switch is set to true then first on should be set to true and so forth. I know that I could use if and else statements to control this, but is there a way to group these together for easier implementation?

```
    <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
        android:id="@+id/switch_all_holes_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Select All Holes"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/switch_front_nine_btn"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

    <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
        android:id="@+id/switch_front_nine_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="Select Front Nine"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/switch_back_nine_btn"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

    <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
        android:id="@+id/switch_back_nine_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="Select Back Nine"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/select_first_nine_btn"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
```

Comment: dont know what architecture you are using, but you could use livedata, observe some boolean and based on it, check / uncheck switches. Every switch would impact this one boolean, which would indicate whether to mark all switches as checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity you need to reference the switches, and apply the changes you want, after one switch is activated

```
firstButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked -> changeOtherButtons()}
)
```

You can update your other buttons in the changeOtherButtons() method - you will need to implement one method for each button, or give the method parameters etc.